# Connection refused by server in redmine plugin client-server application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-server, redmine-plugins

I'm developing a plugin in Redmine which connects to a remote server when I click on a button. But I can't connect to the server. I'm getting the following error:

**Errno::ECONNREFUSED No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2):**

Below is the code that I've written.

_navigation.html.erb

```
<% if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_repository, @project) -%>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto; padding-right: 1%">  
    <%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'GerarVersao')%>
    </div>
|
<% end -%>
```

gerar_versao_controller.rb

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'socket'      # Sockets are in standard library

class GerarVersaoController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

def exec_client
  hostname = 'I put the ip here' #168.192.0.1
  port = 8522
  s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
  s.close               # Close the socket when done 
end

end
```

At server side (server.rb):

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'socket'                # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open(8522)   # Socket to listen on port 8522
loop {                          # Servers run forever
  puts "Aguardando conexao"
  client = server.accept
  client.close
}
```

**Additional Information:**

- The server is on Windows and I have 2 clients (the first on windows and the second on linux) both using the same script listed above.
- The firewall is disabled.
- The server is listening at the port 8522. I checked through the command "netstat /tvan | more"
- The server IP is correct. I checked it through the command ipconfig in the Server Machine. Also I've tried to use the name of the server instead its IP and I got the same problem.

*Important:* I tried a simple connection through another port established by another server (Port 8443 used by SVN Server). The connection was done successfully but when I tried in another port that was not used yet the problem comes back again, which improves even more my questions about it.